# How to make a simulation of a shop queue with switch statement and scan utility?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I have to make a Java program using scan, switch and cases in which I can add one customer with a command "add" and remove one customer with a command "remove".

The default number of customers in queue is 5. If the count of customers gets larger than 8 it prints out "This queue is too big." If there is less than 1 customer it prints out "There's nobody in the queue."

I tried to do some of the code, but I have no idea what to do next.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fronta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println ("This queue has 5 people in it at the moment.");    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean x = true;
    String b = "ADD";
    int a = 5;
    b = scan.nextLine();
    while(x){
    switch (b) {
    case "ADD":
        
    System.out.println ("This queue has " + a + " people in it at the moment.");
    b = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("This queue is too big");
        break;
    
    default:
    case "EXIT":
        System.out.println("End of simulation.");
        x = false;
        break;  
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a good start. Consider adding some if checks which check what you are required to check. Other than that it's hard to help you as it is not clear what part causes you problems.

Comment: Well, the problem for me is how to make it remember the number after it adds or remove the customer. So it adds 1 to 6 for example and not 5 again.

Comment: I assume `a` is your current queue size. Initially it's 5. Just add 1 to it on `ADD` like `a = a + 1` and similarly remove 1 on `REMOVE`. And before doing that check if you've reached queue limits with an if statement (`if (a == 8) // print error` for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need somehting like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isExitRequested = false;
    int queueSize = 5;
    System.out.println ("This queue has "+queueSize+" people in it at the moment.");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        switch (input){
            case "ADD":
                System.out.println ("This queue has " + queueSize++ + " people in it at the moment.");
                if (queueSize > 8) {
                    System.out.println("This queue is too big");
                }
                break;
            case "REMOVE":
                if (queueSize == 0){
                    System.out.println("There's nobody in the queue.");
                } else {
                    queueSize--;
                }
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                isExitRequested = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown input: "+input);
        }

        if(isExitRequested)
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks to you I just had to edit it a bit so it shows the number of customers correctly.

Comment: sure this is kind of draft, you could adopt it to your requirements. but if it can be answer please mark it as answer in order to help others to not check this question anymore